# Magento 2 How to get customer info on resetpasswordpost controller?

Tags: customer-account, magento2.3.1, customer-group, customer-session, forgot-password

Magento 2 How to get **customer info** on `customer/account/resetpasswordpost` controller?

I am trying this code -

```
echo "<pre>";
print_r($this->session->getData());
```

and getting this response only -

```
Array
(
    [wishlist_item_count] => 0
    [rp_token] => XH3BujdKNmcJpc1GQbChU8oYQbwTtiYv
    [no_referer] => 1
)
```

I need to redirect to my custom pages according to customer needs.

For example - 
If customer group is 1 then redirect to xyz page.

If customer group is 2 then redirect to abc page.

Answer (score 0):

You can get customer id in ResetPasswordPost controller by following code:

```
$this->session->getId();
```

And if you want customer data then use below code:

```
$this->session->getCustomerData();
```

You can load customer by id as below:

```
protected $_customer;

public function __construct(
    \Magento\Customer\Model\Customer $customer,
    \Magento\Backend\Block\Template\Context $context
)
{
    $this->_customer = $customer;
    parent::__construct($context);
}

 public function getCustomer()
{
    $customerId = '3'; //You customer ID
    $customer = $this->_customer->getCollection()->addAttributeToFilter('entity_id', array('eq' => '3'));
    print_r($customer->getData());//Customer data by customer ID
}
```

Comment: $customerId = '3'; //You customer ID how to get this dynamically ?

Comment: $this->session->getId(); it is printing 0

Answer (score 0):

Load customer from Id

```
$customerId = (int)$this->getRequest()->getQuery('id');
$customer = $this->customerRepository->getById($customerId);
if($customer->getGroupId()==2){
    $this->_redirect('customer/account/');
}else{
    $this->_redirect('customer/account/');
}
```

Comment: $customerId = (int)$this->getRequest()->getQuery('id'); it is nothing print

Comment: that is customer id or you can get id from current customer session

Comment: $this->session->getId(); i tried this but it is print 0

Answer (score 0):

Finally i solved myself for now using that code -

```
            $sessionData = $this->session->getData();
            $customRpToken = $sessionData['rp_token'];

            $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
            $resource = $objectManager->get('Magento\Framework\App\ResourceConnection');
            $connection = $resource->getConnection();
            $tableName = $resource->getTableName('customer_entity');

            $sql = "SELECT * FROM customer_entity WHERE rp_token = '".$customRpToken."'";
            $result = $connection->fetchAll($sql); 

            $groupId = $result[0]['group_id'];

            if($groupId == 4)
            {
                $resultRedirect->setPath('xyz');
            }
            else
            {
                $resultRedirect->setPath('*/*/login');
            }
```